# entity framework 6 , code first create a table on partition scheme

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, partitioning

I'm using Entity Framework 6.
here is my table entity class:

```
public class MyTable {
[Key]
public long Id{get;set;}
public DateTime TIME { get; set; }
public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

i have created a partition scheme named "DailyPS" and partition function named "DailyPF" using Raw SQL Commands. the partitioning column is TIME
two questions:

1. is there any way to create patition scheme and function using entity framework?
2. how can i create a "MyTable" on partiion scheme?